# appending variable's while using exec()

Tags: php, exec

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>

<?php
    field=$_POST["field1"]
    exec('command 2>&1' $output);
    print_r($output);
?>
```

I am trying to append field to the end of the exec. Field is variable and gets its value from the user by using html form. However I get server `500 error` probably because I am using it wrong.

I have tried:

```
exec('command 2>&1', $field, $output);
exec('command $field 2>&1', $output);
exec('command 2>&1', .$_POST["field1"]. $output);
```

How to use this properly?

Comment: `command {$output} 2>$1;` But it's terribly wrong and not secure.

Comment: What if I check the field1 value is something that I want from user or not by using if before that?

Comment: "exec" + data from the "outside" is a potentially dangerous combination. If you can guarantee full control over the data you execute, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use shell_exec:

```
<?php
    field = $_POST["field1"];
    $output = shell_exec("command 2>&1 ". escapeshellarg($field));
    print_r($output);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
exec("command $field 2>&1", $output);
```

See [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

But since the field comes from unvalidated user input, you should escape it first.

```
exec('command ' . escapeshellarg($field) . ' 2>&1', $output);
```

Comment: Tried this one and the one before but I am getting 500 server error

Answer (score 0):

```
    exec('command ' . escapeshellarg($_POST["field1"]) . ' 2>&1', $output);
    print_r($output);
```

Thank you everyone who posted message to my question. The code above works for me.